# Coefficients in regression output not aligned using stargazer

Tags: html, r, regression, stargazer

I am estimating some models in R and I am using the package `stargazer` to export the results to `html`. However, in the resulting table, the coefficients that are statistically significant are not aligned with the others.

I did the following:

```
c1 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4, data = data)
cov1 <- vcovHC(c1, type = "HC1", cluster = ~country)
robust.se1 <- sqrt(diag(cov1))

c2 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5, data = data)
cov2 <- vcovHC(c2, type = "HC1", cluster = ~country)
robust.se2 <- sqrt(diag(cov2))

stargazer(c1, c2,
          digits = 3,
          align = T,
          dep.var.labels.include = FALSE,
          dep.var.caption = '',
          se = list(robust.se1, robust.se2),
          omit.stat = c('adj.rsq', 'f', 'ser'),
          type = 'html', out = 'regression.html')
```

The output is as in the attached picture.

[Output I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdjfs.png)

Can anyone help me out? Thank you in advance!